# How can i derive this function??

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

I need to find $\frac{\mathrm{d}F }{\mathrm{d} x}$ for $F\left ( x \right )=\cosh^{\sin 2x } \left ( 6x \right )$

But i have no idea how to do it as every single one of my attempts has been wrong.

Comment: Do you mean $[\cosh (6x)]^{\sin 2x}$?

Comment: Is it not the same function?

Comment: If any of the answer below is what you want then that is the same function. If you don't know what the function is, don't expect you can find its derivative. As long as you understand what it is, you may apply standard methods like chain rule or even log differentiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
F(x)&=\cosh^{\sin 2x}(6x)\\
&=e^{\sin2x\cdot\ln[\cosh(6x)]}\\
\implies\dfrac{dF(x)}{dx}&=e^{\sin2x\cdot\ln[\cosh(6x)]}\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\sin2x\cdot\ln[\cosh(6x)]\right]\\
&=\cosh^{\sin 2x}(6x)\cdot\left[\sin2x\cdot\dfrac{6\sinh(6x)}{\cosh(6x)}+\ln[\cosh(6x)]\cdot2\cos2x\right]\\
&=\cosh^{\sin 2x}(6x)\cdot\left[6\sin2x\cdot\tanh(6x)+\ln[\cosh(6x)]\cdot2\cos2x\right]\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of problems, logarithmic differentiation is your friend $$F=\cosh^{\sin (2x) } \left ( 6x \right )$$ $$\log(F)=\sin(2x)\log(\cosh(6x))$$ Now, differentiate both sides $$\frac{F'}F=\left(\sin(2x)\right)'\log(\cosh(6x))+\sin(2x)\left(\log(\cosh(6x))\right)'$$ When finished, use $$F'=F \times \frac{F'}F$$